# Check in all tables in database if two fields are not null, with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase

I would like to check two fields in each tables which name start with X_ into a database !

I've started to write something like :

```
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/myWorkspace.sde"
tables = arcpy.ListTables("X_*")
for table in tables:
    print(table)
```

But now I'm stuck for searching into the tables if there is Field_A and Field_B only filled with NULL values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the da.SearchCursor to create a list of all entries then check list:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/myWorkspace.sde"
tables = arcpy.ListTables("X_*")
for table in tables:
    all_rows = []
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, ['FieldA','FieldB']) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            all_rows.extend(row)
    if all_rows.count(None) == len(all_rows):
        print('{0} is all none'.format(table))
```

Comment: `all_rows.count(None)` will always return `0` because there are no `None` values in the list. Instead there will be a tuple `(None, None)` for all-`None` rows.

Comment: With append that would be true, not with extend

Comment: ah my mistake. I always use append.

Answer (score 1):

@BERA has a good answer but it can be made more efficient by skipping the creation of lists and by breaking the iteration of the cursor if a value is found.

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/myWorkspace.sde"
tables = arcpy.ListTables("X_*")
for table in tables:
    vals = False
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, ['FieldA','FieldB']) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            if row [0] != None or row [1] != None:
                print ("{} fields are not null".format (table))
                vals = True
                break
    if not vals:
        print ("{} fields are null".format (table))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your help both of you !
I finally done something like that :

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/myWorkspace.sde"
tables = arcpy.ListTables("X_*")
emptyTables = []
print "--- Tables where fields Field_A or Field_B are empty or null :"
for table in tables:
    vals = False
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, ['Field_A', 'Field_B']) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            if row[0] == 'NULL' or row[0] == None or row[1] == 'NULL' or row[1] == None :
                 print table
                 vals = True
                 break
     if not vals:
        emptyTables.append(table)
print "------------------"
print "--- Empty Tables :"
for emptyTable in emptyTables:
    print emptyTable
```